# Why this for loop doesn't do the same that the while loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to implement the cocktail sort, and in the main loop I'm trying to use a for loop instead of a while, but it doesn't give me the same results.
Here is the code of the while loop:

```c++
template<typename T>
void cocktail(std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    std::size_t beg = 1;
    std::size_t end = vec.size()-1;
    bool change = true;

    while((beg < end) && (change))
    //for(std::size_t beg = 1, end = vec.size() - 1; (beg < end) && (change); change = false)
    {
        change = false;
        for(std::size_t j = beg; j <= end; j++){
            if(vec[j] < vec[j-1]){
                std::swap(vec[j-1], vec[j]);
                change = true;
            }
        }
        end--;
        for(std::size_t j = end; j >= beg; j--){
            if(vec[j] < vec[j-1]){
                std::swap(vec[j-1], vec[j]);
                change = true;
            }
        }
        beg++;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Before: 3 2 0 9 5 7 8 1 4 6
 After: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

And here is the for loop:

```c++
template<typename T>
void cocktail(std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    //std::size_t beg = 1;
    //std::size_t end = vec.size()-1;
    bool change = true;

    //while((beg < end) && (change))
    for(std::size_t beg = 1, end = vec.size() - 1; (beg < end) && (change); change = false)
    {
        //change = false;
        for(std::size_t j = beg; j <= end; j++){
            if(vec[j] < vec[j-1]){
                std::swap(vec[j-1], vec[j]);
                change = true;
            }
        }
        end--;
        for(std::size_t j = end; j >= beg; j--){
            if(vec[j] < vec[j-1]){
                std::swap(vec[j-1], vec[j]);
                change = true;
            }
        }
        beg++;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Before: 3 2 0 9 5 7 8 1 4 6
 After: 0 2 1 3 5 7 8 4 6 9
```

Do you know why I'm getting different output? My code is located [here](https://github.com/DanielRamosAcosta/sorting-algorithms) if you want to see the main file or something.

Comment: Think about where `change` is set to false in both loops.  One at the beginning, one at the end.

Comment: Wow ok I see it now, thanks a lot I've been looking this for an hour... I'll use the while loop then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your **For** Loop remove **(change = false)** from inside the **for()** statement. Let that **for** statement be

```
for(std::size_t beg = 1, end = vec.size() - 1; (beg < end) && (change);)
{
    // Write here
    change= false;
    ......
}
```

It would work.

**Explanation:** In your **while** loop code, your **change** is set to false at the first step.
But in your **for** loop the **change = false** statement is set to false at the end of the loop. As the third argument of for loop executed as the last statement of the loop.

Consider an example:

**for(i=0;i< n;i++)**

**i** is incremented at last not at first. This is the problem with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

In a `for` loop, the "increment" (3rd part) is executed before the condition (2nd part) is evaluated. In your case

```
for(std::size_t beg = 1, end = vec.size() - 1; (beg < end) && (change); change = false)
```

you are not incrementing a variable, but rather setting `change = false;`. However, this is still executed before the condition is evaluated. Therefore, the condition is always false. In your `while` loop, instead, you are setting `change = false;` **inside** the loop, **after** the condition has been evaluated. This means your 2 loops are not equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    body();
```

is equivalent to

```
size_t i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
    body();
}
```

Your code uses

```
for (bool change = true; change; change = false)
    body();
```

which is equivalent to

```
bool change = true;
while (change) {
    body();
    change = false;
}
```

After the first pass through this loop, change will always be false during the conditional test at the start of the loop.

```
for ( initial ; condition ; iterate )
               ^-------------------v
```